# Alphabet from numbers without delimiters

Tags: javascript, algorithm, cryptography, grouping

If we had our input as **"1125"** and the maximum value as **26** for example, then our output would be:

`[ [1,1,2,5] , [11,2,5] , [1,12,5] , [1,1,25] , [11,25] ]`

that's an array that consists of every possible way to separate the characters to be less than the value **26**.

We can use this to decrypt messages that have been converted letters into alphabetical numbers but without delimiters.

Here's my current code that's my first try to solve this:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfArray=function(array){
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        if(this[i].length==array.length){
            var same=true;
            for(var j=0;j<this[i].length;j++){
                if(this[i][j]!=array[j]){
                    same=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(same){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return-1;
};
function possibilities(string,max){ //The function I'm talking about.
    var output=[];
    (function collector(array,held,start){
        for(var i=start;i<string.length;i++){
            var char=string[i];
            if(Number(held+char)>max){
                array.push(held);
                held=char;
            }else{
                held+=char;
                if(i!=string.length-1){
                    collector(array.slice().concat(held),"",i+1);
                }
            }
        }
        if(held.length>0){
            array.push(held);
        }
        if(output.indexOfArray(array)==-1){
            output.push(array);
        }
    })([],"",0);
    return output;
}
var message="302213"; //"dawn" is "3 0 22 13" with delimiters
var alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var solutions=possibilities(message,alphabet.length);
for(var i=0;i<solutions.length;i++){
    console.log(solutions[i].join(",")+" : "+solutions[i].map(x=>alphabet[Number(x)]).join(""));
}
```

And prints out:

```
3,0,2,2,1,3 : daccbd
3,0,2,2,13 : daccn
3,0,2,21,3 : dacvd
3,0,22,1,3 : dawbd
3,0,22,13 : dawn
3,02,2,1,3 : dccbd
3,02,2,13 : dccn
3,02,21,3 : dcvd
3,022,1,3 : dwbd
3,022,13 : dwn
```

How could I improve this? What's the name of this algorithm?

Comment: Working code that you want 'improved' should go over on [codereview.se], though you should be sure to say *what kind of improvement* you want - execution time? Or...?

Comment: @AakashM Because my algorithm seems to be doing it the wrong way and there must be a better way because how `output.indexOfArray(array)==-1` is required to avoid pushing an array that already exists in the output.

Comment: @Spektre But I had no idea how I would have wrote it from the beginning.

Comment: @AnastasiaDunbar I added C++ example (sorry not a javascript coder) for both <0,25> and <1,26> encoding ranges (your text from start suggest the latter but test sample the first so I coded booth just to be sure) The heuristics is a bit different for the 0 digit the rest is almost the same. Also I think 0? combinations are useless and should be 0,?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different approch for glueing parts together, with 2<sup>array.length - 1</sup> as formular for different chunked parts. Then filter the ones out, which have a value greater than 25.

```js
function split(string) {
    var array = string.split(''),
        result = [],
        i, l = 1 << (array.length - 1),
        v, j,
        temp;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        v = i;
        temp = [array[0]];
        for (j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (v & 1) {
                temp[temp.length - 1] += array[j];
            } else {
                temp.push(array[j]);
            }
            v = v >> 1;
        }
        result.push(temp);
    }
    return result.filter(function (a) {
        return a.every(function (b) {
            return b < 26;
        });
    });
}

function output(array) {
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        console.log(a.join(), a.map(function (b) { return (+b + 10).toString(36); }).join(''));
    });
}

output(split('302213'));
output(split('1125'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is nice example for recursive approach. Let us do some definitions first

1. **Input**

   Input lowercase string `<'a','z'>` is encoded to `<1,26>` without delimiters.
2. **output**

   we want to obtain all decoding of string combinations for each valid decoding 1 vs. 2 digit codes.
3. **Heuristics**

   so 2 digit codes can start with `{ 1,2 }` and `{ 0 }` means that we are handlin 2 digit code `{ 10,20 }` or `{ 0 }` for `<0,25>` this can be used to lower the combinations number.

**Recursive algorithm**

if we have some function like `decode(in);` then we can recursively do this in simple manner like this:

```
decode (string in)
 {
 l=in.Length();
 add_combination(tochar(in[1]) + in.substring(2,l-1));
 add_combination(tochar(10*in[1]+in[2]) + in.substring(3,l-2));
 }
```

In plain words take first `1` or `2` digit character and decode the rest of the string. Let assume your example `1125` the recursions will be as this:

```
||decode(1125)|
 |1|decode(125)|
  |1,1|decode(25)|
   |1,1,2|decode(5)|
    |1,1,2,5|decode()| - combination
   |1,1,25|decode()| - combination
  |1,12|decode(5)|
   |1,12,5|decode()| - combination
 |11|decode(25)|
  |11,2|decode(5)|
   |11,2,5|decode()| - combination
  |11,25|decode()| - combination
```

The intendation represent recursion layer, the first part is current combination prefix (`in0`) and right part is the rest of string to decode (`in1+i`).

This sounds easy but to code this kind of feedback is bit more complicated. That is because wee need to remember a list of solutions instead of one. I decided to store all results in single string separated by `\r\l` end of lines. Here working **VCL/C++** example:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString txt_encode0(const AnsiString &in)    // <'a','z'> ->  <0,25>
    {
    int i,l=in.Length();
    AnsiString txt="";
    for (i=1;i<=l;i++) txt+=int(in[i]-'a');
    return txt;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString txt_encode1(const AnsiString &in)    // <'a','z'> ->  <1,26>
    {
    int i,l=in.Length();
    AnsiString txt="";
    for (i=1;i<=l;i++) txt+=int(in[i]-'a'+1);
    return txt;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_decode0(AnsiString &out,AnsiString in0,const AnsiString &in1,int i,int &l) // recursion <0,25> -> <'a','z'>
    {
    // stop recursion if whole string processed
    if (i>l) { out+=in0+"\r\n"; return; }
    int a0,a1;
    // load first 2 digits from i if second digit is not applicable set is as -1
              a0=in1[i]-'0'; i++;
    if (i<= l) a1=in1[i]-'0'; else a1=-1;
    if (a0> 2) a1=-1;   // >2 means always 1 digit code
    if (a0==0) a1=-1;   // =0 means always 1 digit code
    // one digit combination
    in0+=char(a0+'a');
    txt_decode0(out,in0,in1,i,l);
    in0.SetLength(in0.Length()-1);
    // 2 digit combination
    if (a1>=0)
        {
        a0*=10;
        a0+=a1; i++;
        if (a0<=26)
            {
            in0+=char(a0+'a');
            txt_decode0(out,in0,in1,i,l);
            }
        }
    }
AnsiString txt_decode0(const AnsiString &in)    // <0,25> -> <'a','z'>
    {
    int l=in.Length();
    AnsiString in0="",out="";
    txt_decode0(out,in0,in,1,l);
    return out;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_decode1(AnsiString &out,AnsiString in0,const AnsiString &in1,int i,int &l) // recursion <1,26> -> <'a','z'>
    {
    // stop recursion if whole string processed
    if (i>l) { out+=in0+"\r\n"; return; }
    int a0,a1;
    // load first 2 digits from i if second digit is not applicable set is as -1
              a0=in1[i]-'0'; i++;
    if (i<=l) a1=in1[i]-'0'; else a1=-1;
    if (a0> 2) a1=-1;   // >2 means always 1 digit code
    // one digit combination
    if (a1!=0)          // =0 means always 2 digit code
        {
        in0+=char(a0+'a'-1);
        txt_decode1(out,in0,in1,i,l);
        in0.SetLength(in0.Length()-1);
        }
    // 2 digit combination
    if (a1>=0)
        {
        a0*=10;
        a0+=a1; i++;
        if (a0<=26)
            {
            in0+=char(a0+'a'-1);
            txt_decode1(out,in0,in1,i,l);
            }
        }
    }
AnsiString txt_decode1(const AnsiString &in)    // <1,26> -> <'a','z'>
    {
    int l=in.Length();
    AnsiString in0="",out="";
    txt_decode1(out,in0,in,1,l);
    return out;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main()
    {
    AnsiString enc,dec,txt;
    txt="decoding";
    enc=txt_encode0(txt);
//  enc="302213";
    dec=txt_decode0(enc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `txt_encode0,txt_decode0` operates on `<0,25>` and `txt_encode1,txt_decode1` operates on `<1,26>` range.

The `out` is holding list of valid combinations. `in0` holds actual prefix of combination `in1` hold the input string. `i` is start index for actual combination in `in1` and `l` is length of `in1`. Here the output for `<0,25>`:

```
message:decoding
encoded:3421438136
decoded in [   0.013 ms]

decbedibdg
decbeding
decodibdg
decoding
devedibdg
deveding
```

and your sample:

```
encoded:302213
decoded in [   0.007 ms]

daccbd
daccn
dacvd
dawbd
dawn
```

I am using `AnsiString` from **VCL** they are self allocating dynamic strings with indexing from `1`. For example `AnsiString s="abc";`  `s[1]=='a'` The size of it is `s.Length()` so `s[s.Length()]=='c'`.

Comment: @AnastasiaDunbar possibly due to different calling convention of operands: `const AnsiString &in1`  means that `in1` is not changing so only reference pointer of it is send (no duplicating in heap), `AnsiString &out` means that `out`  is changing but has only single instance durring all recursion calls (also on reference pointer and no heap duplicating), `AnsiString in0`  means a copy of the `in0` is created for each recursion.  I do not know how it is in javascript but you can fake the `const type &` and `type &` with global variables. Also ansi string is indexed form `1` instead of zero.

Comment: @AnastasiaDunbar as I mentioned before I do not code in javascript so I cant tell. you can compare my and yours result during the same input that would tell the difference.   Also `"a".charCodeAt(0)` can be changed to `97` and `'0'.charCodeAt(0)` to `48` which are ASCII codes ... I see no recursion calls inside `txt_decode0,txt_decode1` nor the tail `in0,in1,i` nor result `out` all but `in0,i` can be as global variable instead but I do not see that either

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive approach in JavaScript. The idea is if the next two characters in the string can be interpreted in two ways, add each of the two ways to each result in splitting the next part of the string. Otherwise, add just the first character to each result in splitting the next part of the string.

```js
function possibilities(str){
  if (str.length === 0) return [[]];
  
  var result = [], next = possibilities(str.substr(1));
        
  for (var i=0; i<next.length; i++)
    result.push([str[0]].concat(next[i]));

  if (str.length > 1 && str[0] !== '0' && str.substr(0,2) < 27){
    next = possibilities(str.substr(2));
        
    for (var i=0; i<next.length; i++)
      result.push([str.substr(0,2)].concat(next[i]));
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(possibilities('1125'));
console.log(possibilities('302213'));
```